# CSS Padding Stretching Divs: Internet Explorer Vs. Chrome/Firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Hello StackOverflow community,
I have run into a problem that quite frankly is baffling me and I am surprised that I haven't run into this problem sooner.

Apologies if I have overlooked something simple - I have done extensive Google and StackOverflow searches to no avail.

My problem is that when applying a padding to a Div the container is stretched by the specified padding amount in Firefox/Chrome but not in IE.  I have seen suggestions for adding "display:inline;" or "display:inline-block;" to fix the problem but this has effect for me.

Here is an rendered example:
[image: http://img825.imageshack.us/img825/7190/testpic.jpg]

And the code for this example:

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
#div1 {
background-color:black;
width:400px;
height:300px;
padding-top:10px;
}

#div2 {
background-color:red;
width:400px;
height:280px;
padding-top:10px;
}

#div3 {
background-color:blue;
width:400px;
height:260px;
padding-top:10px;
}

#div4 {
background-color:green;
width:400px;
height:200px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="div1">
<div id="div2">
    <div id="div3">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="div4">
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

What am I missing?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `<!DOCTYPE ... >` is what you're missing. IE is rendering in Quirks mode, where the box model is border-box and not content-box.

Comment: Thank you so much.

I thought that might have been the problem previously but when I tested it I must have chosen the wrong doctype or maybe it was caught in the cache.

Irreguardless I am so greatful I am sure you saved hours of headache.

Thank you, Kolink!